# how to compare snapshots using dotmemoryunit

Tags: unit-testing, memory-leaks, jetbrains-ide, dotmemory

So I've started running memory leak tests using Jetbrains.DotMemoryUnit nuget package, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var mcp1 = dotMemory.Check();

// lots of automation testing using TestStack.White

dotMemory.Check( memory =>
    Assert.That( memory.GetDifference( mcp1 )
        .GetSurvivedObjects().GetObjects( where => where.Namespace.Like( "XXX" )  ).ObjectsCount, Is.EqualTo( 0 ) ));
```

All of our internal namespaces have a format like XXX.UI.ModuleName.

However on running the test it's not asserting when there's a memory leak, and I've put in several deliberately (and several not deliberately)

Any idea where I'm going wrong here?  (I'm assuming it's in the where part if anywhere)

---

Just to be certain I changed the way I was getting the snapshots so that I was using

dotmemoryapi.GetSnapshot

I have then manually opened my two snapshots to compare them, and there's nothing mentioning my XXX namespace.

However if I perform the exact same memory test using the profiling too, but manually pressing the buttons, there are a lot of entries with the XXX namespace.

Honestly not got a clue what's going on here.

Comment: Are you sure that you get snapshots manually exactly at the same time as in unit test? Look who holds objects declared in namespace "XXX*" maybe it will clarify what is the difference.

Comment: I think I found out what the problem was  

It looks like when I using the snapshot under automation tests, rather than hooking into my application, it was instead hooking into the test runner.